# Heroku - How to monitor requests and responses?

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, logging

I have several spring-boot based micro-services on Heroku platform.
They using http API to communicate each other.
And I need some tool (it can be heroku add-on, spring feature or other tool) to monitor how they communicate (see all requests and responses).
I know that I can implement custom spring http interceptors and store http messages somehow but it will be better to use already ready solution.

Comment: if you want to monitor requests you might wanna try newrelic or raygun

Comment: Or log relevant data. You're asking a very broad question, and unfortunately it's off-topic for multiple reasons. You can read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing is to log to stdout, using any logging library or simply printing, and have heroku logs display it on the command line.